# C++ pointer with address without referencing address

Tags: c++

So if I wanted to create a pointer but I wanted to write the address instead of doing a variable referencing it how would I do something like this?

instead of this

```
void* ptr = *point_to
```

and do something like this

```
void* ptr = (7ffc505ce660)
```

Comment: Why do you need that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use the correct syntax for a hexadecimal number literal, and cast it to the destination datatype (in this case, `void*`)

`void* ptr = reinterpret_cast<void*>(0x7ffc505ce660);`

Answer (score 4):

Quite likely to lead to undefined behaviour but if you really must then you can just `reinterpret_cast`:

```
void* ptr = reinterpret_cast<void*>(0x7ffc505ce660ULL);
```

Comment: Appears to not actually be [Undefined behavior](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/reinterpret_cast) but rather implementation defined. However the cast may need to go through `std::uintptr_t` first.

Comment: @Mgetz I did say "likely to lead to undefined behaviour", depends what the random number means, and what is going to be done with `ptr`. I can't envisage any way you'd know at compile time what a valid address at runtime would be

Comment: @AlanBirtles You could know that in a case where it's stated in the manual of the system that you are targeting.

Comment: @AlanBirtles embedded DMA addresses spring to mind. There are videos of people using C++17 to program old consoles too where there are fixed addresses.

Answer (score 2):

An integer can be converted to a pointer with a reinterpret_cast. Note that the behaviour of indirecting through such reinterpreted pointer (after reinterpreting to a pointer type that can be indirected) would be undefined unless the documentation of your system specifies otherwise. Such exception is probably not going to be the case on a system that uses virtual memory.

This is sometimes used in practice as a minor optimisation in C interfaces where you can pass custom data to a callback function as a `void*`, in which case passing single integer would be most efficient and safest to reinterpret to and back from `void*` instead of indirecting through the pointer to access an integer elsewhere.